# Why can't I install virtualenv? what is No matching distribution error?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am new to python and I want to install virtualenv to do something.

I have tried to use pip and easy_install to install it, but I get error message about distribution issue.

My os is MacOS 10.12.6, and I have installed `pycharm` in my system before.

This is `sys.path`

```
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

**easy_install**

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv

Searching for virtualenv
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'virtualenv' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for virtualenv
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('virtualenv')
```

**pip**

```
sudo pip install virtualenv

The directory '/Users/posen/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/posen/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting virtualenv
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

I am not able to understand what is happening, can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: What version of pip?

Comment: do this first `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python` then try to install again

Comment: This is the problem: *"Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)"* - Are you behind some sort of TLS proxy?

Comment: The site is using an encryption that isn't understood by your ssl library. Have you tried updating your libraries? TLSv1 has been deprecated as of June 30, 2018. Check this [PCI security blog](https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/are-you-ready-for-30-june-2018-sayin-goodbye-to-ssl-early-tls) out.

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

Comment: @aws_apprentice Opps, It's work. The pip update to 18.0, then virtualenv install successfully.

Comment: If it's older than 9.0.2, you'll need to upgrade your pip version. *glad you got it working

Comment: @GrantMcCloskey Thank a lot!

Comment: Personally, I would suggest using pyenv rather than virtualenv directly. Or get miniconda. And please use Python3 for any new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [problem](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4436) occurs due to pip older versions. To solve it you can upgrade pip to the latest version by using this command.

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

the procedure to follow to resolve the problem is as follows:

1. upgrade PIP `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. upgrade virtualenv `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`